# change value form after press button (django)

Tags: html, mysql, django, python-2.7

I have a form where when I select my option and press the "Select" button I need to update the form with the data of my selected object. My problem is that when I do my static object the {% for%} already marks me an error because it is not a list. I do not know if this is the correct way to do it.

This is running Mysql, django 1.11 and python 2.7.15

views.py

```py
def administrador(request):
    alumno = Alumnos.objects.all()
    mapa = mapas.objects.all()
    competencias = Competencias.objects.all()
    context = {
        'alumno': alumno,
        'mapa': mapa,
        'competencias': competencias
    }
    return render(request, 'competencias_app/competencias.html', context)

def seleccion(request):
    alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(pk=request.POST['Nombre'])
    context = {'alumno': alumno}
    return render(request, 'competencias_app/competencias.html', context)
```

competencias.html

```html
 <form action="/seleccion" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <select id="carrera" name="Carrera">
                    <option value="1">TICS</option>
                    <option value="2">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="3">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="4">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="5">Carrera</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <select id="Alumno" name="Nombre">
                    {% for alumno in alumno %}
                    <option value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}">{{alumno.nombre}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input type="submit" name="Seleccionar">

                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="ID">ID</label>
            <input type="input" name="id" disabled value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}"><br>
            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="input" name="apellidos" disabled value="{{alumno.apellidos}}"><br>
            <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
            <input type="input" name="Correo" disabled value="{{alumno.correo}}"><br>

        </form>
```

the output when press "seleccionar" is

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/seleccion
Django Version: 1.11.21
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'Alumnos' object is not iterable

[Images for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHGRe.png)

Comment: `alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(pk=request.POST['Nombre'])` retun single object or None. So, you don't need iterrate over single object.

Comment: right, but in my server the mistake is  {% for alumno in alumno %} where alumno is not list.

Comment: put `{% if alumno % }` and `{% end if%}` around the `<select></select>` box.  Also, I am not certain you can do a `for loop` where the iterator is the same variable as the list object.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with one if, i don't know if is the correct solution but works!

competencias.html

```html
 <form action="/seleccion" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <select id="carrera" name="Carrera">
                    <option value="1">TICS</option>
                    <option value="2">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="3">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="4">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="5">Carrera</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <select id="Alumno" name="Nombre">

                    {% if alumno|length > 1 %}
                    {% for alumno in alumno %}
                    <option value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}">{{alumno.nombre}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                    <option value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}">{{alumno.nombre}}</option>
                    {%endif%}

                    <input type="submit" name="Seleccionar">

                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="ID">ID</label>
            <input type="input" name="id" disabled value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}"><br>
            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="input" name="apellidos" disabled value="{{alumno.apellidos}}"><br>
            <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
            <input type="input" name="Correo" disabled value="{{alumno.correo}}"><br>

        </form>
```

views.py

```py
def administrador(request):
    alumno = Alumnos.objects.all()
    mapa = mapas.objects.all()
    context = {
        'alumno': alumno
    }
    return render(request, 'competencias_app/competencias.html', context)

def seleccion(request):
     lstCompetencias = []
     alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(pk=request.POST['Nombre'])
     for p in Competencias.objects.raw('Select * from test_app_competencias where idmapasfk_id = %s', [request.POST['Nombre']]):
         lstCompetencias.append(p)
     context = { 
         'alumno' : alumno,
         'competencias' : lstCompetencias
        }

     return render(request, 'competencias_app/competencias.html', context)
```